# Error con las rutas en vue2 cuando paso a producción

Tags: vue.js, vue2

Cuando compilo mi proyecto de vue2 para pasar a producción y estoy navegando no puedo refrescar la pagina porque me devuelve este error si no estoy en la ruta raíz. Apache/2.4.54 (Win64) PHP/8.0.26 mod_fcgid/2.3.10-dev Server at "nombre del dominio" Port 80. Estoy empleando vue router